# How to add a bounding box to a composite shape in Roassal 3?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, roassal

I'm trying to draw a bounding box around a group of shapes. I get everything in the scene, but I don't know how to make the bounding box and the text get correctly aligned:

[image: Result]

```
    c := RSCanvas new.
    text := RSGroup new.
    foo := RSLabel new text: 'foo'.
    bar := RSLabel new text: 'bar'.
    text add: foo; add: bar.
    RSVerticalLineLayout on: text.
    bound := RSShapeFactory box
        model: self;
        border: (RSBorder new width: 1; color: Color black);
        cornerRadius: 5;
        width: text encompassingRectangle width + 15;
        height: text encompassingRectangle height + 10.
    all := RSComposite new shapes: { bound. text asShape }.
    c add: all.
    c  @ RSCanvasController.
    ^ c
```

Comment: Why do you do RSVerticalLineLayout ?

Comment: The Pharo Discord https://discord.com/channels/223421264751099906/300020095844089856 gives you answers faster

Comment: @snorik to put the text one line below the other. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @StephanEggermont I know, but answers there get forgotten with time, stackoverflow serves much better to keep a kind of faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is how I did it. The missing key point was to put an RSLocation.

[image]

```
    c := RSCanvas new.
    text := RSGroup new.
    foo := RSLabel new text: 'foo'.
    bar := RSLabel new text: 'bar'.
    text add: foo; add: bar.
    RSVerticalLineLayout on: text.
    bound := RSShapeFactory box
        model: self;
        border: (RSBorder new width: 1; color: Color black);
        cornerRadius: 5;
        width: text encompassingRectangle width + 15;
        height: text encompassingRectangle height + 10.
    contents := text asShape.
    all := RSComposite new shapes: { bound. contents }.
    RSLocation new center; outer; stick: contents on: bound.
    c add: all.
    c  @ RSCanvasController.
    ^ c
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another solution

[image]

```
text := 'Foo
bar'.
label := RSMultilineLabelBuilder new shapeFor: text.
box := RSBox new 
    fromRectangle: label encompassingRectangle;
    cornerRadius: 10;
    noPaint
    withBorder.
box extent: box extent + 15.
all := { box . label} asGroup asShape.

canvas := RSCanvas new.
canvas add: all.
canvas @ RSCanvasController
```

Maybe in a future we can add an extension method for strings `'hello world' asRoassalShape`.